# Upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 has hung

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, upgrade

I am currently running an upgrade from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 and the system has hung at :

Installing new version of config file /etc/mysql/debian-start ...

It says there are about 4 minutes remaining.

Please direct me on what to do next.  My knowledge of ubuntu at a technical level is sparse but I can work my way through instructions and command line stuff.

I'm not touching the process until I get some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an upgrade over SSH or just a standard desktop upgrade?

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/321724/ubuntu-server-upgrade-over-ssh-hang) seems to suggest that just stopping `mysql` might do the trick, and that makes sense to me so open up a terminal and fire in `sudo stop mysql` or `sudo service mysql stop` and see what happens. Obviously if this is a server, ssh in and run the above.

Comment: Sorry should have said it is a desktop upgrade.  Tried what you suggested but nothing happened.  Any way I rebooted the m/c and it booted fine and it is showing the current version as 11.10.  I think it was sufficiently late in the upgrade process that all the main stuff had already happened.  Unfortunately I have manged to clobber mysql which is what I'm trying to find a fix for now.  Thanks for your input.  Not sure how to mark this as 'case closed'.

Comment: Since writing the above comment I'm having huge problems with starting mysql.  Complains that the socket at /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock is not present.  The question I have here is :  Is there a way of restarting an interrupted upgrade?

Comment: @Purvez Your packages list should be updated so a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` should get you to a relatively sensible place.

Comment: Thanks that is useful to know as I have other m/cs to upgrade as well.  For the current one I removed and purged mysql and then re-installed and everything is working fine now.